# Object of class App\Class could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to perform a check to see if a user scored ($get_reslts_score) above the requirements ($passing_grade), then the user passed. Here is the code I've tried.

```
 $get_reslts_score= Exam::with('exam_results')->first();

            $x = $get_reslts_score->passing_grade;
            $calculations = 100 * $get_reslts_score;
            $total_percentage = $calculations/$x;


            // if($exam_result->result >= $x) {

              if($x >= $total_percentage) {
              $exam_result->is_complete = 1;
              $exam_result->save();
            }
```

I'm getting the following error

Object of class App\Exam could not be converted to int

Comment: Error message says it all. Perhaps you wanted to multiply by one of the object's properties? Or maybe `$calculations = 100 * $x`?

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, that was the error. $calulations = 100* $x.

Answer (score 1):

```
$get_reslts_score= Exam::with('exam_results')->first();
$x = $get_reslts_score->passing_grade;
$calculations = 100 * $x;
$total_percentage = $calculations/$x;

              if($x >= $total_percentage) {
              $exam_result->is_complete = 1;
              $exam_result->save();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot multiply by the object of the model: `$get_reslts_score;` you have to make a reference to a field in the database which you have done in `$get_reslts_score->passing_grade;` by assigning the result to `$x;` that is okay.

you can now use $x to perform your calculation. hope i'm correct.

```
$get_reslts_score= Exam::with('exam_results')->first();

            $x = $get_reslts_score->passing_grade;
            $calculations = 100 * $x;
            $total_percentage = $calculations/$x;


            // if($exam_result->result >= $x) {

              if($x >= $total_percentage) {
              $exam_result->is_complete = 1;
              $exam_result->save();
            }
```